# Tag selection: recognize words with :: in them as a whole

Tags: c++, vim

I'd like vim to recognize `foo::bar` as just one word when doing a tag-search using `Ctrl-]`.

In regular settings, `:` is not part of a keyword, so reading http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27iskeyword%27, I thought I could get away with:

```
set iskeyword+=\:
```

This indeed does work for the above example, but it has the unfortunate effect that `foo:` is also recognized as a keyword as well. (Where I'd like only `foo` to be recognized if my cursor is indeed on `foo:`.)

Is there a way to allow `::` be part of a keyword, only when it comes in a pair? (The pathetic cases of having three consecutive `:`'s etc. can be ignored for a practical solution.) The `iskeyword` setting seems to only allow individual characters, not pairs like this.

*Motivation:* This is a practical concern in a C++ like language with namespaces, where `::` is used to form one identifier (as in `NameSpace1::NameSpace2::foo`), but just having `foo:` should simply ignore the final `:` and search the tag file for a definition of `foo`.

*CTAGS/C++* I understand that ctags does not generate tags of this form for C++, but I'm experimenting with an alternative tag generation strategy.

Comment: BTW. What is `foo:`? A label in C++?!

Comment: @Matt Yes, could very well be a label.

Comment: this is most likely not possible. of course you could remap all the relevant movements to fit your needs, but that will require some work

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "remap all the relevant movements?"